# what Parameters needs to considered while moving webform model to MVC pattern of ASP.NET framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have gone all over internet however still confuse in choosing MVC or WEBform pattern of ASP.NET Framework.
i have an application which is Developed on Webform model, does it really require to move it to MVC?

Webform is quiet stable, why should we go for MVC? 
I mean what parameters we need to consider before moving webform model project to MVC?

any help or redirection will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a webform app... and it works... leave it. If you're starting a greenfield project. Use MVC.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there is nothing special that forces you to move into MVC.
If you’re going to start a new project consider using MVC. Here are few points which you could get benefited while using ASP.NET MVC :

> 1. Asp.Net MVC is a lightweight and follow MVC (Model, View, Controller)    pattern based development model.
> 2. Asp.Net MVC has html helpers.
> 3. Asp.Net MVC does not support view state. Asp.Net MVC has route-based    URLs means URLs are divided into controllers and
>      actions and moreover    it is based on controller not on physical
>      file.
> 4. Asp.Net MVC follow    customizable syntax (Razor as default)
> 5. In Asp.Net MVC, Views and    logic are kept separately.
> 6. Asp.Net MVC   has Layouts for consistent    look and feels.
> 7. Asp.Net MVC has Partial Views for code re-usability.
> 8. Asp.Net MVC is lightweight, provide full control over markup and    support many features that allow fast & agile development. Hence it
>      is best for developing interactive web application with latest web
>      standards.
> 9. Asp.Net Web MVC is Open Source.